# how to get projectID value from dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

need to extract projectID  and my final output is to be 1868117666669.

```
'{
    "code":"ok",
    "job":{
        "config":{
            "progress":{
                "message":"Reading 2014-03-03__12-57-01-PM.xml",
                "percent":107,
                "maxmemory":954,
                "memory":667
            },
            "projectID":1868117666669,
            # other stuff
            }
        }
  }'
```

Comment: & what have you tried in this regard?

Comment: That's not a Python dictionary, that's a string containing JSON data.

Comment: okay.how to extract data from it

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
>>> a = '{"code":"ok","job":{"config":{"progress":{"message":"Reading 2014-03-03__12-57-01-PM.xml","percent":107,               "maxmemory":954,"memory":667},"projectID":1868117666669}}}'

>>> json.loads(a)['job']['config']['projectID']
1868117666669
```